How to generate .exe file for KMP project?
I can run cammand of
gradle nativeBinaries
But after run this command I'm facing this issue. I found this commands on Kotlin/Native
`

What went wrong:
Task 'nativeBinaries' not found in root project '' and its subprojects.
`
Check error image

I want to create .exe file. So i can install it on my computer. I'm using Kotlin Multiplatform.
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.dsl.ExperimentalWasmDsl
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.webpack.KotlinWebpackConfig

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
}

kotlin {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalWasmDsl::class)
    wasmJs {
        moduleName = "composeApp"
        browser {
            commonWebpackConfig {
                outputFileName = "composeApp.js"
                devServer = (devServer ?: KotlinWebpackConfig.DevServer()).apply {
                    static = (static ?: mutableListOf()).apply {
                        // Serve sources to debug inside browser
                        add(project.projectDir.path)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        binaries.executable()
    }
    
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "11"
            }
        }
    }
    
    jvm("desktop")
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach { iosTarget ->
        iosTarget.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "ComposeApp"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        val desktopMain by getting
        
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
        }
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
            implementation(libs.voyager.navigator)
            implementation(libs.voyager.screenModel)
        }
        desktopMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.<ProjectName>"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()

    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.<ProjectName>"
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.android.targetSdk.get().toInt()
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    dependencies {
        debugImplementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling)
    }
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "com.<ProjectName>"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}

compose.experimental {
    web.application {}
}


I don't think anyone would be able to answer your question without a lot more detail. What sort of application are you building? What target (Linux/Windows/MacOS) are you building for? [edit] your question and add the contents of your build.gradle.kts.

As stated in the link you provided in your question, if you want to have native targets, you must have the following in your build.gradle.kts file:
kotlin {
    macosX64("native") { // on macOS
    // linuxX64("native") // on Linux
    // mingwX64("native") // on Windows
        binaries {
            executable()
        }
    }
}

This part is missing from the file you pasted.
(Uncomment the Linux and/or Windows lines as appropriate.)
